# "The project file was unloaded" when moving VS2010 project to another server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have moved a Visual Studio 2010 project to another server by copying and pasting the folder contents into another folder on a different server.

My understand was that VS2010 handled this well; when I have done this locally it has never been an issue.

Now I get an error like this:

[image]

When I right click and "Reload project", the list of files briefly appears before disappearing again, giving the original error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This can also happen in VS2017

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this problem today and it took me a while to figure out what was going on.

Your problem is most likely that your solution was originally made with a Visual Studio configuration that contained support for certain project types (such as "Windows Service" or some other exotic project type). The Visual Studio configuration you are using to import your solution does not have that support. In other words,

- there is probably nothing wrong with your solution,
- there is probably nothing wrong with your project,
- there is probably nothing wrong with any of the files (as you mentioned they do display briefly, giving you a second of hope)

Just run the installer on the new Visual Studio and make sure the support is enabled for all the project types you need and try again.

Comment: Hard to believe, but C/C++ and the Windows SDKs are NOT part of the default installation for Visual Studio 2015.  And whoever decided not to give a useful error message for this should be chastised.

Answer (score 68):

I experienced the same problem today. Here is what I did and worked for me :

1. Open the .sln file.
2. Right click on the project folder and click Reload project.
3. You will see the projects and folders that you originally had.
4. You will see  .xml publish file . Double click it .. You should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks!  The reloading project did it for me though it needed to install "Common Tools" for it to work

Comment: Thank you,,, anyways, so people kept re installing and repairing VS while it was just a very tiny click....

Comment: This needs to be the selected answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. I don't really need to visit the installer again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the .vbproj file had somehow been corrupted so the normal xml code was replaced with a long string of null characters. I noticed this thanks to a file that was generated in the same folder as the project file when I tried to open the project - it was called 'UpgradeLog.htm'. This had an entry saying ' Error on line 1. Expected '<' but found 'null character'.'.. suggests there may have been a recent update to Visual Studio that I hadn't noticed?

Luckily I could use my source control system to revert back to a slightly earlier version - I guess it shows how important it is to have backups!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I saw similar message (Projected was unloaded) and all I had to do was simply re-launching Visual Studio (2017) in Admin mode and the problem went away. Per one of the above answers, I tried to right-click and selected Reload but got a warning that, due to required access to IIS on the machine, I had to launch VS in Admin mode.

HTH

Comment: Same with me.I was using Local IIS in my asp-mvc project. So, I have to start visual studio as administrator everytime to load the project

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer and it worked for me.

*Note:Sometimes, the path in File path property is grayed out and you are unable to get to the Browse button. In this case try deleting .suo files. Don’t worry, these files gets recreated when you rebuild the solution / project.*

http://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fix path to .csproj files in the .sln file with a text editor and now it is all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio as **Administrator**