# All projects in a solution now fail to load in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a solution that I was actively working on a month or so ago in Visual Studio 2017. Now when I try to open it each of the projects is listed as "unavailable, the project file was unloaded" in the solution explorer:

[image: VS2017 screenshot]

There is no diagnostic output in the output window. I think the solution is still OK because it opens without issue in Visual Studio 2015:

[image: VS2015 screenshot]

This happens on both my laptop and my desktop PC (but not on an Azure VM). Right-clicking and reloading the projects has no effect.

How do I diagnose what is wrong?

Comment: Any error message when you open solution?

Comment: @qxg I do mention that in the question, the answer's "no"

Comment: @roshan_nazareth, my apologies, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roshan_nazareth points out in a comment that my question may be a duplicate of another question: [“The project file was unloaded” when moving VS2010 project to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24267783/575530). One one of the answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169199/575530) suggests that the solution was made for project types that the current installation of Visual Studio has no support installed. That seems to be the issue, I had not noticed this option on the right-click menu for the failing projects:

[image: VS2017 screenshot]

The "Install Missing Feature(s)" option kicks off the Visual Studio installer for the missing component, in my case an earlier version of the Windows 10 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to right click the unavailable project and simply select 'reload project'.
If the entry in solution file is corrupted then right click on each of the projects and select 'unload project'.
Then right click the solution icon and click add->existing project.
Browse for an unloaded project and add it.